# Magento 2 - enable cash on delivery only for specific shipment method in New Order in Backend

Tags: magento2

I used a Plugin in a custom module to set the isAvailable function for CashOnDelivery to false when shipping method "flatrate_flatrate" is selected.

file: /app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/Plugin/CashOnDeliveryPlugin.php

```
<?php
    namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin;
    use Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
    class CashOndeliveryPlugin
    {

      /**
       * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
       */
       protected $_checkoutSession;

      /**
       * Constructor
       *
       * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
       */
        public function __construct
        (
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
         ) {
            $this->logger = $logger;
            $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
            return;
        }

        public function aroundIsAvailable(\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod $subject, callable $proceed)
        {
            $shippingMethod = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
            if ($shippingMethod == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
                return false;
            }
            $result = $proceed();
            return $result;
          }
    }
```

and file: /app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery">
        <plugin name="cashondeliveryplug" type="MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin\CashondeliveryPlug" disabled="false" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

It works fine in frontend checkout, but doesn't work in New Order in Backend. What should I change in code to make it functional in Backend Order Creation?